# My return PartialView opens up a new page instead of being on the same page?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, controller, partial-views

**I am trying to display a Quick Search field at the top of my page. After clicking search a partial view should open up the results.
What i am getting is instead a new page with the search results?!**

## View with the RenderPartial:

### Displaying the search box

```
<div style="height: 20px;padding:0" class="panel-heading">Quick Course Search</div>
<div style="height: 20px;padding:0" class="panel-body">

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CourseSearch", "Courses",

            new AjaxOptions
            {
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                HttpMethod = "GET",
                OnFailure = "searchFailed",
                LoadingElementId = "ajax-loader",
                UpdateTargetId = "searchresults",

            }))
{
    <input type="text" name="q" />
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/ajax-lader.gif")" style="display:none" />
}

<div id="searchresults">



</div>
```

## PartialView:

### Displaying the search results as a list

```
@model IEnumerable<HoneyMustard.Interface.Models.Courses>



<div id="searchresults">
<ul>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li>@item.CourseName</li>

    }
</ul>


</div>
```

## Controller:

### Querying the database

```
 public ActionResult CourseSearch(string q)
    {
        var courses = GetCourses(q);

        return PartialView("~/Views/Courses/CourseSearch.cshtml", courses);
    }

  private List<Courses> GetCourses (string searchString)
 {    


               return db.Courses.Where(a =>       a.CourseName.Contains(searchString))
                .ToList();


    }
```

Comment: Please answer the question. Dont really understand why you commented it as a duplicate?

Comment: Because if your getting a new page, rather than updating the existing page it mean your `Ajax.BeginForm()` is acting as a normal form because you have not included the relevant scripts. Read the Dupe!

Comment: I have added all the scripts needed and still does not work! Do I need to change the unobtrusive in web.config file to false?

Comment: No, it should be `<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />` What if any errors are you getting in the browser console? If your redirecting to a new page rather than updating the existing page, it means that the scripts are not working and a normal submit is being made.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package shop1;

/**
 *
 * @author Pc
 */
public class NewJFrame1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame1
     */
    public NewJFrame1() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(77, 77, 77)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 115, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(198, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(129, 129, 129))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(84, 84, 84)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 119, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(54, 54, 54))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        print
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```